# C-LibCurl crash when init : curl_global_init() and curl_easy_init()

Tags: c, crash, libcurl

I'm trying to run some basic libCurl code in C, but I notice that for all my attempts, my programs crash at initialization (curl_global_init() or curl_easy_init()).
Even with this tiny little test, the crash program. And none of my 2 printf() - before or after - are displayed.

I get an error code: "Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    CURL *tcurl;
    printf("Before crash\n");
    tcurl = curl_easy_init(); //  exactly crashes in this statement.
    printf("After crash\n");
    curl_easy_cleanup(tcurl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to help me?

I'm on Windows 10, I use Cmake to compile.

Thank you very much!

Comment: While debug-printing is useful to print values and find calculations which misbehave, it's usually not so good to find the exact location of crashes. Always use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, and see when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: Do as @Someprogrammerdude suggested. Also always check the return value of functions. Here is a minimal example which should work: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

Comment: If the program is really crashing inside `curl_easy_init` when called as the first operation in `main`, then the problem is _probably_ that your CURL DLL was compiled in a way that conflicts with the way your main program was compiled.  Where did you get it?

Comment: Potential exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008921/c-libcurl-curl-easy-init-gives-an-access-violation-error-and-crashes-the-pr?rq=1 (but I'd like some more evidence before I get out the hammer).

Comment: I downloaded the sources from the curl web site then I built it with Visual Studio. So I have a .dll and a .lib. I did it again to make sure there was no conflict.
I already tried the debugger but it don't tell me where it crash, not very usefull there :s

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue today. Below is the GDB stack trace

```
#1  0x0000555555d99d5d in CRYPTO_STATIC_MUTEX_lock_write ()
#2  0x0000555555d22d4a in CRYPTO_get_ex_new_index ()
#3  0x00005555557b37f3 in ossl_init ()
#4  0x000055555578054b in global_init ()
#5  0x00005555557808e9 in curl_easy_init ()
```

This was because the custom compiled SSL and ZLIB libraries by another library (other than curl library) that was linked with my program.

I removed that library and it started working fine.

Just posting it here, so that it may help you.

However this is was in linux. Similarly on windows there might be some SSL or CRYPTO package that is creating the issue for you. Just check if curl libraries you have downloaded are based on WinSSL or OpenSSL. That might give some idea.